# Use Pandas and socket.gethostbyname to fill missing IP address of a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, pandas

I just recently started using pandas. I am trying to fillna of IP address column by resolving the hostname using sockets.gethostbtname().

Below is a sample DataFrame called data

```
      domain      ip_address
0   google.com           NaN
1   yahoo.com           NaN
```

I have the following code:

```
data.ip_address =  data['ip_address'].fillna(socket.gethostbyname(data.iloc[data.index]['domain']))
```

but i get the error below:

```
TypeError: gethostbyname() argument 1 must be str, bytes or bytearray, not Series
```

Answer (score 1):

The error which you got is because `socket.gethostbyname` function is expecting a string or a byte string but the input is a Series.
Whenever we perform non-iterative operations on Pandas Dataframe, they internally iterate over a Series.
So, here you are extracting a Series and passing that Series as an argument to `socket.gethostbyname`.

So, here we can use "map" to solve this:

```
import socket
import pandas as pd
# Creating a dataframe with your input
data_in = [{'domain': 'google.com', 'ip_address': None},
 {'domain': 'yahoo.com', 'ip_address': None}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data_in)
df['ip_address'] = df['domain'].map(lambda host:socket.gethostbyname(host))
```

Now, this df2 will be as below.

```
       domain      ip_address
0  google.com  172.217.26.174
1   yahoo.com  98.139.180.149
```

The above resolution of host name to ip works only if all the host names are valid. Suppose, if you have any un-resolvable host name anywhere(say test1989), this would fail and the dataframe would not be altered.